# DataFrame Combining Columns Conditionally

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 28 columns. I want to combine 2 of the columns together conditionally to create a new column, which will become my key when I manipulate the data and bring in other data sets. I will have to create the key again in each of the data sets.

I want to concatenate the columns 'CN' and 'ON' together. Sometimes 'ON' is blank or just has a space, so I need to trim it first. Logically, I am trying to do the following.

IF Trim('ON') IS BLANK THEN 'CN ON' = 'CN' ELSE 'CN ON' = 'CN'+'-'+'ON'

**DataFrame**

```
   CN  ON    POC
0  W1      Name1
1  Z2      Name3
2  B3  YY  Name1
3  W1  A2  Name4

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'CN': ['W1', 'Z2', 'B3', 'W1'],
                   'ON': ['', ' ', 'YY', 'A2'],
                   'POC': ['Name1', 'Name3', 'Name1', 'Name4']
                   })
```

**Desired Results**

```
   CN ON  CN  ON    POC
0     W1  W1      Name1
1     Z2  Z2      Name3
2  B3-YY  B3  YY  Name1
3  W1-A2  W1  A2  Name4

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'CN ON': ['W1','Z2','B3-YY','W1-A2'],
                   'CN': ['W1', 'Z2', 'B3', 'W1'],
                   'ON': ['', ' ', 'YY', 'A2'],
                   'POC': ['Name1', 'Name3', 'Name1', 'Name4']
                   })
```

I found some similar questions and answers, but I wasn't able to quite get something to work.

Here is what I have so far. I am having trouble figuring out how to trim and check if the field is blank. It's not currently working, and I feel like I've hit a wall.

```
import numpy as np
df['CN ON'] = df.apply(lambda r: (r['CN'] if np.where(df['ON'].applyman(lambda x: x == '')) else r['CN'] + '-' + r['ON'])
```

Any guidance or assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you look at the Pandas docs?

Comment: I did as I was researching the problem. I didn't understand how to implement any conditional check for blanks. However, there are diverse and great solutions posted below. Now I have a better understanding, and I will continue to develop on this foundation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do string sum

```
(df.CN+ '-' + df.ON).str.strip('- ')
Out[98]: 
0       W1
1       Z2
2    B3-YY
3    W1-A2
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.cat` and `mask`

```
df.CN.str.cat(df.ON, '-').mask(df.ON.str.strip().eq(''), df.CN)

Out[903]:
0       W1
1       Z2
2    B3-YY
3    W1-A2
Name: CN, dtype: object
```

If you want to insert it to the beginning of the `df`, use `insert` with position 0

```
s = df.CN.str.cat(df.ON, '-').mask(df.ON.str.strip().eq(''), df.CN)
df.insert(0, 'CN ON', s)

print(df)

Out[906]:
   CN ON  CN  ON    POC
0     W1  W1      Name1
1     Z2  Z2      Name3
2  B3-YY  B3  YY  Name1
3  W1-A2  W1  A2  Name4
```

---

Note: `df.insert` is `inplace` operation, so you don't need assign back. It directly modifies `df`

Comment: Lots of functions I haven't used before in here. I'm not quite sure I fully understand. So the mask function trims leading and trailing spaces and if it's equal to '' (blank), then just use df.CN. The beginning concatenates df.CN, df.ON, and '-'? How does the mask override the beginning concatenation? If I'm correct in any of that.

Comment: `str.cat` joins `CN` to `ON` returns series `'W1-', 'Z2- ', 'B3-YY', 'W1-A2'`. On `mask` True, values got replaced by values of `df.CN`. `mask` is True at `'W1-', 'Z2- '`, so they got replaced by `'W1', 'Z2 '`. The final series is `'W1', 'Z2', 'B3-YY', 'W1-A2'`. The `df.mask` works as the condition: `if condition True, replace values by specifies values; otherwises, leave them alone`

Comment: I appreciate the assistance and the explanation! That really helps me a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
In [242]: df
Out[242]:
   CN  ON    POC
0  W1      Name1
1  Z2      Name3
2  B3  YY  Name1
3  W1  A2  Name4

In [243]: df['CN-ON'] = df.apply(lambda x: '{}{}'.format(x['CN'], '-' + x['ON'] if x['ON'].strip() else ''), axis=1)

In [244]: df
Out[244]:
   CN  ON    POC  CN-ON
0  W1      Name1     W1
1  Z2      Name3     Z2
2  B3  YY  Name1  B3-YY
3  W1  A2  Name4  W1-A2
```

Comment: For learning purposes, would you mind explaining how your solution works?

Comment: Sure, it's just going row by row with `.apply()` and then uses native Python string formatting to make the desired combination. It'll almost certainly be slower than the other answers that use string methods, but would be useful in situations where your combining logic might be more complex.

Comment: Greatly appreciated! This will most definitely be useful in the future once I get more advanced in my Python. I am going to be saving this one for sure!